# Printing Unicode Characters From android to bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: android, unicode, printing, bluetooth

I have bluetooth/usb thermal Printer of model QS58.
I want to print unicode characters like "मराठी"

When i connect printer to computer through usb and give print,it prints correctly.
but, when printing through my android application it is printing invalid characters(chinese character).

I think windows is sending correct data to printer,but my application not.so please
tell me ho can i send data to printer.

I have already tried following methods

```
mmOutStream.write("मराठी".getBytes("UFT-8"));

mmOutStream.write("मराठी".getBytes("UFT8"));

mmOutStream.write("\u0991\u0992".getBytes("UFT-8"));

mmOutStream.write("\u0991\u0992".getBytes());
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got your encoding as "UFT-8". Should this not be "UTF-8"??

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to do that. 
In documentation states that it only prints:

*Printable content:
English, numbers, symbols,   Chinese characters*

also
*Instruction set:
ESC/POSCompatible   instruction set*

So maybe your charactares (i don't know what language is that) are in some region page code of ESC/POS.

Comment: so how to use page code for thermal printer in java?

Comment: He doesn't mention which QS-58xx model he uses. A few (QS-5801, QS-5803, QS-5806) of the models seem to support Unicode character set. http://www.qsprinter.com/product/2inch-bluetooth-label-printer.html